# Converting Google analytics 2d array values to suitable format for c3/d3.js line graph

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-analytics, c3.js

So I'm having trouble converting the column/row data returned from the core reporting API, into a format I can use with c3.js to plot a line graph. Here is an example of the returned data rows:

```
"[["20151025","Direct","1"],["20151025","Organic Search","1"],["20151025","Referral","1"],["20151026","Direct","1"],["20151026","Organic Search","8"],["20151026","Referral","1"]]"
```

It includes the date, type and number of sessions.

I would like to convert it to JSON where it would look like this:

```
                    json: [{
                        "day": "20151025",
                        "Direct": "1",
                        "Organic Search": "1",
                        "Referral": "1"
                    }, {
                        "day": "20151026",
                        "Direct": "1",
                        "Organic Search": "8",
                        "Referral": "1"
                    }]
```

I have tried to map the value doing something like this:

```
var data = response.result.rows.map(function(row){return {day:row[0], type:row[1], hits:row[2]}});

[{"day":"20151025","type":"Direct","hits":"1"},{"day":"20151025","type":"Organic Search","hits":"1"},{"day":"20151025","type":"Referral","hits":"1"},{"day":"20151026","type":"Direct","hits":"1"},{"day":"20151026","type":"Organic Search","hits":"8"},{"day":"20151026","type":"Referral","hits":"1"}]
```

...but as you can see their are 3 separate entries with the same day, I would need to combine/merge the elements with same day value into a new element.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated... I've been searching all around and can't seem to find a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Search on the term 'pivot table' for a suitable algorithm.